# Why am I encountering stackoverflow in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I have a int, "count" that adds one after each recursion, but I also have an if statement that stops the recursion once the int is equal to, or greater than another integer. Somehow that if statement is ignored.

```
public static boolean wildcard(String x, String y, int substring, int count) {
    if (count >= y.length()){
        System.out.println("asdf");
        return true;
    }

    if (x.charAt(count) == y.charAt(count)){
        System.out.println("ALSKDFJKL");
        return wildcard(x, y, substring, count++);
    }
    if (y.charAt(count) == '*'){
        return wildcard(x.substring(substring), y, substring++, count);


    System.out.println("wildcard end");
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: How do you know the `if` statement is ignored?

Comment: because if it wasn't ignored, the recursion would end

Comment: *Can someone explain why I'm encountering stackoverflow?* - because you have a programming question that you need help answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `return wildcard(x, y, substring, count++);` try `return wildcard(x, y, substring, ++count);`

`count++` is a post increment (meaning it will increment AFTER the method returns)

You will probably also want to update `return wildcard(x.substring(substring), y, substring++, count);` for the same reason.

Also, your last `if` statement is broken...I think the `System.out` and `return false` want to be outside the `if` block